# RPi3 wireless issue CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=16

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi

It appears the wifi is working, and the device can see my SSID. However when it connects it gets an error:

`CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=16`

I checked my router and the 2.5 GHz network settings. I have seen many posts with similar issues and none seem to have the resolution I need. I did a full apt update/upgrade and rebooted several times.

How do I troubleshoot this issue and get the wifi working?

Comment: Never have I felt so close to another soul... and yet so helplessly alone

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem with a Raspberry Pi 4B. In my case, it was related to the [fast roaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11r-2008) feature. To temporarily disable it for the Broadcom WiFi driver, run the following two commands:

```
rmmod brcmfmac
modprobe brcmfmac roamoff=1
```

Afterwards, try to connect to your access point again:

```
wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

If the connection was successful, you can persist the `roamoff` setting by creating `/etc/modprobe.d/brcmfmac.conf` with the following content:

```
options brcmfmac roamoff=1
```

Answer (score 3):

To add on [Tim's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119866/149806), after encountering this issue with a rpi 3A+ and a rpi 4B (both using the BCM4345), running Raspios bullseye (09-2022, arm64, lite version), I was able to fix it by using :

```
modprobe brcmfmac roamoff=1 feature_disable=0x82000
```

See [my answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/140524/149806) to [RPI 3B wlan0 wifi adapter broken?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/91659/26774) for more details.

EDIT: For anyone interested in the specifics of that `0x82000` value, see the [offloading article on iwd's wiki](https://iwd.wiki.kernel.org/offloading), mainly :

> The brcmfmac driver has a module parameter called 'feature_disable'. It expects a hex value (bitmask) where each bit corresponds to a feature.
> [...]
> This will disable both SAE (0x80000) and FWSUP (0x02000).

Comment: NOTE: to make these changes permanent, do as [Tim's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119866/94071) suggests. Set these flags in `/etc/modprobe.d/brcmfmac.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error today on a Raspberry Pi 400.  In my case I believe it may be power related.

After much searching, and trial and error, I unplugged a decade old mouse with fancy LED lighting.  I had substituted the old mouse for a wireless mouse with a flat battery.  The problem immediately went away.  I suspect the old mouse with the fancy lights may have overtaxed the system, or possibly it was generating some kind of electrical or radio interference.

While searching, I also saw a report where changing the monitor from one HDMI port to another fixed the issue.

There are also reports that changing the wireless channel sometimes helps.

When faced with this issue, as well as looking at the wireless configuration,  try reducing or changing the connected hardware and see if it makes any difference.